# Are onCreate onCreateView etc. guaranteed to be called from a single thread

Tags: android, documentation

Is there a documentation that guarantees that Android's onCreate(), onDestroy(), onCreateView() etc methods shall only be called from one thread that is Application's main thread.

Does any documentation makes such guarantee for future versions of Android?

I am looking for documentations supporting/refuting this.

Thanks

Comment: onCreate() and onDestroy() of activities are called by OS wheres if you're talking about onCreateView() that means you're talking about fragments because it is fragment life cycle method and fragments life cycle methods and called by the host activity of fragments , you can rely on them with no worries because google is not going to brake the existing applications code.

Comment: I am aware that they are currently called in main thread. I am just looking for documentation that guarantees this.

Comment: was my answer any help?

Answer (score 0):

Google is the authority to publish the documentation so you can't find documentation anywhere else , so  this article by goole  -> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle  about activity life cycle should clear all of your doubts.

And Now The Guarantee Thing

*onDestroy() and onStop() may not be called. This would occur in a
few circumstances:*

**• You crash with an unhandled exception**

**• The user force-stops your application, such as through the Settings app**

**• Android has an urgent need to free up RAM (e.g., to handle an incoming
phone call), wants to terminate your process, and cannot take the time to
call all the lifecycle methods**

Hence, onDestroy() and onStop() is very likely to be called, but it is not guaranteed, but under same circumstances odds of stop() being called is higher then onDestroy().

All others methods are guaranteed to be called , you can freely rely on them.

Upvote if you find it helpful , thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for documentation on which thread will call method, not whether method will be called.